# Ubuntu 16.04 won't relinquish wired connection for wireless

Tags: wireless, network-manager

Ubuntu 16.04.1 xenial on bare metal Intel NUC.

I've been using a wired connection for sometime now and wish to now switch to wireless (relocating box).

I've connected to the wireless router. A notification comes up saying I'm connected to it. The connection information says my active network connection is to that wireless router with an IP of 10.1.1.205, and a default route and DNS of 10.1.1.1.

The wired connection was 10.1.1.3.

But when I ping the gateway at 10.1.1.1 it says:

```
From 10.1.1.3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I've tried the below that I've read elsewhere (eg. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1576215) is meant to fix this problem:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But this doesn't fix the problem and I cannot use the wireless network.

Any ideas?

---

### Updated with more information

- Based on initial comments

  $ cat /etc/resolv.conf

  # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
  #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
  nameserver 4.4.4.4
  nameserver 127.0.1.1

  $ cat /etc/network/interfaces

  # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg

  $ ls -la /etc/network/interfaces.d/

  total 4
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 165 Dec 30 10:48 eth0.cfg

  $ cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0.cfg

  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
  # address 192.168.1.4
  address 10.1.1.3
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  # gateway 192.168.1.1
  gateway 10.1.1.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 4.4.4.4

I haven't tried the `modprobe` suggestion in a comment as it sounds permanent.  I will do a bit of reading first.

### Further investigations

Doesn't this seem odd:

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"starkiller24"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx   
      Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-29 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:42   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.

$ sudo ifup wlan0
Unknown interface wlan0
```

Would creating an interface in `/etc/network/interfaces.d` help?  And if so why hasn't one been created?

Comment: Is the wired connection unplugged ?

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: George was right. You need to simply unplug the Ethernet cable or remove the driver from the Kernel (`modprobe -r driver_name`) and then the WiFi should automatically take over.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'll update the question and try the suggestion tongiht (12 hours).

Comment: Oh, and i had unplugged the ethernet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in my answer I had the interface for `eth0` defined in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0.cfg`.  I simply had to remove that and wireless now works!  So must be some kind of automatic configuration must be happening.

I played around with defining a `wlan0.cfg` but that was unnsuccessful.  I'm sure I just had a settings mismatch and I will attempt this task again at another time (for educational purposes).